# scala spark extract share logic into a function and used in aggregation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following function which calculates aggregation:

```
def compute(spark: SparkSession,
                  mydf: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    
  mydf
    .groupBy(col("col1"), col("col2")
    .agg(
      count(when(col("col5") === "some_string_to_check", col("purchase_date"))).as("name1"),
      count(when(col("col5") === "some_string_to_check", col("purchase_date"))).as("name2"),
      count(when(col("col5") === "some_string_to_check"), col("purchase_date"))).as("name3"),
      count(when(col("col5") === "some_string_to_check"), col("purchase_date"))).as("name4"),


      count(when(col("col5") === "some_string1", col("purchase_date"))).as("name10"),
      count(when(col("col5") === "some_string1", col("purchase_date"))).as("name11"),
      count(when(col("col5") === "some_string1"), col("purchase_date"))).as("name12"),
      count(when(col("col5") === "some_string1"), col("purchase_date"))).as("name13")
    )
}
```

as you can see this function has repeated pattern (I show 2 but there are 10+ of these) since this is a repeated code I'd like to extract the common logic into a function. something like (pseudo code):

```
def compute(spark: SparkSession,
                  mydf: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    
  mydf
    .groupBy(col("col1"), col("col2")
    .agg(
      func("col5", "some_string_to_check", "purchase_date", ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"]),
      func("col5", "some_string1", "purchase_date", ["name10", "name11", "name12", "name13"])
    )
}


def func(col, string_to_compate, date_col, array_of_name_results) = {
  count(col === string_to_compate, col(date_col))).as(array_of_name_results[0]),
  count(when(col  === string_to_compate, col(date_col))).as(array_of_name_results[1]),
  count(when(col  === string_to_compate), col(date_col))).as(array_of_name_results[2]),
  count(when(col === string_to_compate), col(date_col))).as(array_of_name_results[3]),
}
```

Can this be done? I couldn't find any reference if it's possible to use function to create the logic of `.agg()`? Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Luis, have a look at the `Aggregator` class (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/Aggregator.html). I haven't implemented it myself but I think that's what you're looking for. I haven't completely read the following article, but it seems like this will help you further: https://towardsdatascience.com/using-the-spark-aggregator-class-in-scala-341ee8bb46e5

Comment: @Koedlt thanks! can you give some skeleton pseudo code how would that apply in my case? I'm having hard time understanding how the example in the article apply in my case

Comment: Spark comes with a bunch of examples  that demonstrate usage of many APIs. For example, https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.3/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/SimpleTypedAggregator.scala

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the function signature for `agg` you'll see:

```
def agg(expr: Column, exprs: Column*): DataFrame
```

Given this, we can create a list of aggregate `Column` expressions and pass those in:

```scala
def calculate(spark: SparkSession,
              mydf: DataFrame): DataFrame = {

  def func(col: Column, string_to_compate: String, date_col: String, array_of_name_results: Array[String]): List[Column] = ???
  val aggregates = func(col("x"), "y", "z", Array.empty)
  mydf
    .groupBy(col("col1"), col("col2"))
      .agg(aggregates.head, aggregates.tail:_*)
}
```

It's not quite as elegant to look at as a pure method call, but does allow you to reuse the logic bundled in `func`.